# Trouble with the proof for Nielsen's form of Lagrange's equation.

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

I just cannot understand how the step transition happened. Please please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate each of the three terms on the right with respect to $\dot{q_j}$:

Since $T$ does not depend on $\ddot{q_i}$, 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q_j}}\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot{q_i}} \ddot{q_i}\right) = \frac{\partial^2\,\,T}{\partial q_i\partial q_j}
$$

However, since $T$ does depend on both $q_j$ and $\dot{q_j}$, the second term will lead to two contributions:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q_j}}\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i}\dot{q_i} \right) = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \dot{q_j}\partial q_i}\dot{q_i}+ \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i}   \frac{\partial\dot{q_i}}{\partial\dot{q_j}} = 
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \dot{q_j}\partial q_i}\dot{q_i}+ \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i}   \delta_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \dot{q_j}\partial q_i}\dot{q_i}+ \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j}   
$$
And the third term is obvious:
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q_j}}\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}\right)
= \frac{\partial^2T}{\partial\dot{q_j}\partial t}
$$